# ZK ComboBox onchange changes all comboboxes in the listbox

Tags: combobox, inline, onchange, zk

I have an issue with a listbox and the combobox behaviour. I have a listbox with a group of rows and I try to edit inline and change the value of a field based on the values of a combobox. But when I select one value in the combo of one row then all the values of the comboboxes of the other rows change to the same value. Please, let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

```
            <template name="model" var="item">
                <listitem >
                    <listcell label="@load(item.id)"/>  
                    <listcell label="@load(item.descCodigoTrafico)"/>              
                    <listcell label="@load(item.descAmbitoDeTrafico)"/>
                    <listcell>
                        <combobox 
                            model="@load(vm.listaPrecioEspecial)" 
                            onChange="@command('addToUpdate', entry=item)"
                            selectedItem="@load(item.precioEspecial) @save(item.precioEspecial, before='updateItems')">
                            <template name="model" var="el">
                                <comboitem label="@load(el)"/>
                            </template>
                        </combobox>
                    </listcell>
                    <listcell label="@load(item.tipoDescuento)" />
                    <listcell>
                        <decimalbox inplace="true" 
                        value="@load(item.ppm) @save(item.ppm, before='updateItems')"
                        onChange="@command('addToUpdate', entry=item)" 
                        format="#.0000"/>
                    </listcell>
                </listitem>
            </template>
```

And the code of the two methods in de VM:

```
    @Command
public void addToUpdate(@BindingParam("entry") TblEscenarioCondTrafico item){
    itemsToUpdate.add(item);
    LOGGER.info(item.toString());
    for(TblEscenarioCondTrafico i : itemsToUpdate){
        LOGGER.info("Item a guardar " + i.toString());
        //LOGGER.info("Elemento...");
    }
}

@NotifyChange("listaTraficos")
@Command
public void updateItems() throws Exception{
    EscenarioCondTraficoService ects = new EscenarioCondTraficoService(em);
    for (TblEscenarioCondTrafico i : itemsToUpdate){
        LOGGER.info("Guardando " + i.toString());
        ects.save(i);
    }
    itemsToUpdate.clear();
    listaTraficos = getListaTraficos();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be that

```
model="@load(vm.listaPrecioEspecial)"
```

sets the same `Collection` to every `Combobox` as its model and so it is bound to all `Combobox` instances.

Comment: Hi Nabil A. Thanks for your answer! This could be the cause. Do you know any approach to avoid it? Do I have to set a new model for every row?

Comment: Let `getListaPrecioEspecial()` return a copy of the List (?). But be aware, Java has no deep clone/copy! So if the objects in your list are not from a framework that supports deep clone, you could not simply create new instances and you do not want to implement the clone your self, which I recommand, if the data structure is not too complex, you could use [this](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/). If you do so, please read the instructions on the site.

Comment: Thanks Nabil A. for your comment. I'll try and let you know. The data structure is a List with a few strings, and it will be about ten combos for every page, so I assume that it will be not a big load of data. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, like Nabil A. said the problem was the model, the same for all the items. I solved creating a new model for every item.
Instead of:

```
model="@load(vm.listaPrecioEspecial)"
```

I put something like:

```
model="@load(vm.getNewListaPrecioEspecial())
```

And in the VM class you have to create a method named getNewListaPrecioEspecial that returns a new list. (In my case a new SortingPagingListModel)